# temporary IIS .NET assembly randomly deleted/missing

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I am hosting a WCF service in IIS.  Randomly lately I have been getting an error that takes down the service:

[error pic http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/7579/errorp.png](http://img543.imageshack.us/img543/7579/errorp.png)

The assembly it is looking for is located in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files folder.  Im thinking an improper app pool shut down would cause this, but I am not sure.  The server is a Win2003 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue a while back. I never nailed down the cause, but with changes and framework upgrades it went away. Here is a [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/986130.a) on the issue.